# Custom metadata tags Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, metadata, next.js13

Is there a way to create custom metatags with next 13 and control if it should be “name” or “property”?

I was trying to add some Facebook metatags like ‘og:updated_time’ , but that key isn’t there and using ‘other’ doesn’t work since it uses ‘name’ instead of property.

Answer (score 2):

For custom meta tags you can use following

```
export const metadata = {
  other: {
    custom: 'meta',
  },
}
```

In your case, it could be

```
export const metadata = {
  other: {
    'og:updated_time': 'your-data',
  },
}
```

For open graph, there is a openGraph field. See - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Blog',
  openGraph: {
    title: 'Blog',
  },
}
 
// Output:
// <title>Blog</title>
// <meta property="og:title" content="Blog" />
```

Also checkout - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadata-fields

```
export const metadata = {
  openGraph: {
    title: 'Next.js',
    description: 'The React Framework for the Web',
    type: 'article',
    publishedTime: '2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    authors: ['Seb', 'Josh'],
  },
}
```

Comment: But it doesn’t include all fields. The one in my example isn’t there.

Comment: Try adding `updatedTime` ignoring any type errors and see if the meta tag is applied in build

Comment: I tried, it didn’t add the field. And if I use ‘other’ for a custom field, it adds ‘name’ for ‘og:updated_time’ instead of ‘property’.